# How can I make a program that reacts to finding a color pixel by playing a sound?

Tags: vb.net

I'm new to scripting and I'm trying to create a program that will:

Play a soundfile when it finds a specific color on the screen.  I would want it to be a simple program with a start button and a stop button.

Once I press start I want it to look search for a specific color on the screen, once it finds the color it will play a soundfile.  The color pixel pops up at random intervals so I want it to just monitor my screen till the color pixel appears, then notify my by playing a sound.

The hex code for the color i want it to search for is #7E3200 and the RGB is 126,50,0

Any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just done a bit of googling and this is how you print screen in Vb.net: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/161299 and then this stack overflow post will show you how to find the colour of a specific pixel in a picture box. This would be your flow:

1. Using the Microsoft artice, capture the screen to an image box to the screen.
2. Scan the image in the picture box for that colour.
3. Use a `for` loop to check if that pixel colour is your chosen colour